# Jquery posting with AJAX , How serializing works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create an AJAX request with JQuery to interrupt a form once it has been verified as not being empty and submit that form to a url, then it needs to get those form values and put them into some variables so i can use them for things. The problem is i have no idea how AJAX works and

I have no idea how serializing works and the documentation on it seems rather abstract. I also can't keep the page from switching URLs

```js
newGame.onsubmit = function(e) {
  var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // only validate the inputs that have the required attribute
    if (inputs[i].hasAttribute("required")) {
      if (inputs[i].value == "") {
        // found an empty field that is required
        alert("Enter Player Name!");

      }
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://ins.mtroyal.ca/~nkhemka/process.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#newGame').serialize(), // i have no idea how this works
      success: function loadName() //this would contain the code to get the player names loaded into variables

    }
    e.preventDefault(); // I dont know where this should go to keep the page from going to the URL
  );

}
```

```html
<div class="nGame">
  <form id="newGame" action="http://ins.mtroyal.ca/~nkhemka/process.php" method="post" name="newGame">
    Player 1 Name:
    <input type="text" name="player1" required>
    <br> Player 2 Name:
    <input type="text" name="player2" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="New Game">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` goes at the top of the function body, on the line after `newGame.onsubmit = function(e) {`.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the `e.preventDefault()` goes as long as it's called.

Comment: but it is NOT called

Comment: @JJJ It can't possibly go in the success callback.

Comment: ` $('#newGame').serialize()` is serialize in key value format and your key is your name in input field and value is value in that textbox

Comment: Also do not ajax if the validation fails

Comment: The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select>: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();

Comment: @Svenskunganka If it's in the success callback then it won't be called during the function execution, so what's your point?

Comment: If it is where he put it, the form will always be submitted so what is YOUR point?

Comment: You have a syntax error due to where you put `e.preventDefault()`. It should be a statement inside the `onsubmit` function, not in the arguments to `$.ajax()`

Comment: Also do not ajax if the validation fails - you have jQuery, use it: `$("#newGame").on("submit",function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault(); 
  $("input",this).is("[required]").each(function(el) {
      if ($.trim(el.val()) == "") {
        alert("Enter Player Name!");
        return false;   
      }
    });
 });`

Comment: @mplungjan If it's where he put it he has a syntax error.

Comment: Point is: don't put it there.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't have to be *at the start of the function*. I didn't think that "it can't be where it creates a syntax error" needed to be said out loud.

Comment: @mplungjan The e.preventDefault() doesn't seem to work anywhere i put it at the moment...

Comment: Then there are more issues. Look in the console. It belongs right after the `function(e) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1 :**

1) Added new id attribute in submit input `id="submit"`

2) On click submit id run the function and stop the default form submition usin g `e.preventDefault();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    err = 0;
    $('input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('required') && $(this).val() == '') {
        err = 1;
        alert("Enter " + $(this).attr('name') + " Name");
      }
    });
    if (err == 1) {
      return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://ins.mtroyal.ca/~nkhemka/process.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#newGame').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        // loadName(); 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nGame">
  <form id="newGame" action="http://ins.mtroyal.ca/~nkhemka/process.php" method="post" name="newGame">
    Player 1 Name:
    <input type="text" name="player1" required>
    <br> Player 2 Name:
    <input type="text" name="player2" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="New Game">
  </form>
</div>
```

1) `e.preventDefault();` it prevent the default form submission action

2) If any of field is empty you should stop calling ajax using `return false;` .

```
if(err==1)
  {
     return false;

     // any of fied is empty you should retun false to stop calling ajax request

  }
```

3) `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();

4) If you need to call another function on ajax it should be like this

```
success: function()
      {

         loadName() //this would contain the code to get the player names loaded into variables

       }
```

**Ajax :**

```js
newGame.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // it prevent the default form submition action 
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    err = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].hasAttribute("required")) {
        if (inputs[i].value == "") {
          err = 1;
          alert("Enter Player Name!");
        }
      }
    }
    if (err == 1) {
      return false;
      // any of fied is empty you should retun false to stop calling ajax request
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ins.mtroyal.ca/~nkhemka/process.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#newGame').serialize(),
        // .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select>: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();
        success: function(res) {
          loadName() //this would contain the code to get the player names loaded into variables
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: The page keeps going to the process.php page when using this,

Comment: did you used this  e.preventDefault();  line on top of jquery like where i placed in my code @Tristen

Comment: wait a minute i'm doing some changes in your code @Tristen

Comment: I tried it and it STILL somehow, despite it working fine above loads the php page, it does tell if the inputs are empty but it will then go to the php if i fill in both inputs

Comment: first of all you should be know the  use of ajax . ajax is used  requesting server and get the server response without page re loading so it should not change the url on browser @Tristen

Comment: Just a heads up i figured it out. Turns out i managed to repeatedly neglect to include Jquery libraries in my html over and over again for the last 8 hours. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `ajax` and form serialization works like:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'http://ins.mtroyal.ca/~nkhemka/process.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 
    {
        frmData : $('#newGame').serialize();  // It will send value like index1=value1&index2=value2
    },
    success: function(response)
    {
        // Check the response value and show alert
    }
});
```

process.php

```
$frmData = $_POST['frmData'];
$params = array();
parse_str($frmData, $params);

print_r($params);
```

It will give all form values on 0, 1, 2.. index like:

```
array(
    'index1' => 'value1',
    'index2' => 'value2'
    // and so on
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume that you want to post a form which have some field, wrapper them as

```
var formNewGame = { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};
```

In your ajax call, change

```
data: $('#newGame').serialize()
```

into

```
data: JSON.stringify(formNewGame );
```